# duplicate uploaded files by different users at the same time php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem:
When a user points to different properties, a photo from one property can be displayed on the photo of another property. I noticed that sometimes the pictures that are in the wrong property have them in the right property, and sometimes they are gone, but I do not know how to solve this problem. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
 if(is_array($_FILES)) {
        $br = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
        echo $br;
       foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$val)
        {
            $br--;

            $sql3 = "SELECT id FROM property_images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";  

            $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
            $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();

            $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $sourceProperties = getimagesize($file);
            $fileNewName = $row3['id'] + 1;
            $folderPath = 'properties_pic/'.$date.'/';
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];
            $sql3 = "SELECT id FROM property_images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

                $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
                $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();

            switch ($imageType) {


                case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                    $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                    $file=imagepng($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpeg");
                    break;

                case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                    $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file); 
                    $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                    $file=imagegif($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpeg");
                    break;


                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                    $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file); 
                    $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                    $file=imagejpeg($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpeg");
                    break;


                default:
                    echo "Invalid Image type.";
                    exit;
                    break;
            }
                    if($file)
                    {
                        //Image db insert sql


                        $fileNewName = $fileNewName.'.jpeg';
                        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO property_images (id_property, name_image, folder_image, date_upload, user_id) VALUES ('$id', '$fileNewName', '$date', '$date2', '$user_id')";

                        if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE)
                        {
                             $sql44 = "UPDATE properties SET pic='1' WHERE id=$id";
                             $conn->query($sql44) === TRUE;

                            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
                        }


                    }

        }   

    }
}

}
function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height) {


if($width>$height)
{
    $targetWidth = $width;
    $targetHeight = $height;
    while($targetWidth>800)
    {
        $targetWidth = $targetWidth/1.1;
    }
    while($targetHeight>600)
    {
        $targetHeight = $targetHeight/1.1;
    }

}
else
{
    $targetWidth = $width;
    $targetHeight = $height;
    while($targetWidth>600)
    {
        $targetWidth = $targetWidth/1.1;
    }
    while($targetHeight>800)
    {
        $targetHeight = $targetHeight/1.1;
    }
}

    $targetLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$targetWidth,$targetHeight, $width,$height);


    return $targetLayer;
}
```

Comment: _"I noticed that sometimes the pictures that are in the wrong property have them in the right property"_ - That made zero sense. Your question is _very_ confusing. Please explain what you mean by "property" and what the code is suppose to do. Don't ask us to read all your code and guess. Remember that we have _no idea_ what your application does/suppose to do. We are 100% dependent on you to explain it to us.

Comment: When multiple users upload photos simultaneously, sometimes one or more pictures are displayed in several properties where they are not uploaded but only when pictures are uploaded simultaneously by different users

Comment: `SELECT id FROM property_images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` retrieves the `id` of the very most recently inserted row into `property_images`. It's a notorious SQL antipattern. If user A and user B work at uploading things simultaneously, it's likely they'll sometimes retrieve each others' data.  Take a look at the code that accepts uploads from your users. It should associate each uploaded image with the correct property as it is uploaded.

Comment: the id of the most recent inserted row into property_images I use it to see the sequence number of the next upload photo. For example, if SELECT id FROM property_images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 returns me 777, the next uploaded image should be named 778 and accordingly saved in property_images

Comment: Look up "race condition."  Your web server can be processing multiple user requests at the same time.